# Paypal Sandbox API Test

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have created a test API on Paypal

[image]

Do you know what i have to put in this function to make it work ?

```
  // Creates a configuration array containing credentials and other required configuration parameters.
  public static function getAcctAndConfig()
  {
    $config = array(
        // Signature Credential
        "acct1.UserName" => "",
        "acct1.Password" => "",
        "acct1.Signature" => "",
        // Subject is optional and is required only in case of third party authorization
        //"acct1.Subject" => "",        

        // Sample Certificate Credential
        // "acct1.UserName" => "certuser_biz_api1.paypal.com",
        // "acct1.Password" => "D6JNKKULHN3G5B8A",
        // Certificate path relative to config folder or absolute path in file system
        // "acct1.CertPath" => "cert_key.pem",
        // "acct1.AppId" => "APP-80W284485P519543T"
        );

    return array_merge($config, self::getConfig());;
  }
```

Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 0):

- Username is your email address
- Password is likely the ClientID
- Signature is likely the Secret

You should log into your Sandbox (the actual PayPal Sandbox site, not just Developer) account and verify that is the case

Comment: This not well explained on Paypal website but I understood that i have to go to 'accounts' to get all this informations.